# Using a custom class with FragmentTabsPager under ActionbarSherlock

Tags: android, tabs, android-viewpager, actionbarsherlock

I'm building an Activity that uses tabs which can also be horizontally swiped.  I'm also using Actionbar Sherlock (ABS) for pre 3.0 compatibility.

I found a good implementation of the FragmentTabsPager with ABS from Stackoverflow user Sparky on http://code.google.com/p/sherlock-demo/source/browse/#git%2Fsrc%2Fcom%2Fexample%2Fandroid%2Fsherlockdemo.

It sets up an adapter as follows:

```
String[] mAccts;  // source data for the list

// populate mAccts with an array of Strings ...

setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String> (getActivity(),
                R.layout.simple_list_item_checkable_1,
                android.R.id.text1, mAccts));
```

This works fine if the list item is a String, but my listview item happens to have two strings plus an image.  So I've tried changing the code to work with my custom class as follows:

```
ArrayList<MyItem> mItems = new ArrayList<MyItem>();  // new source data

// populate mItems with an array of MyItems ...

setListAdapter(new MyItemAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.my_list, mItems));
```

Where MyItemAdapter is

```
public class MyItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MyItem> { ... }
```

MyItemAdapter also includes a getView() function to pull out the right fields from MyItem and inflate the my_list XML.

PROBLEM: It seems like the above changes should work, but the class from which setListAdapter() is called in the example is declared statically, and MyItemAdapter makes a call to getSystemService(), which is not static.  The result is I get an error:

```
Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getSystemService(String)
```

I tried making the calling function non-static, but that seems to break the example code.

Any ideas how to fix this?  I appreciate any and all help!

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer to my problem.  Since the calling class was actually inside a Fragment, I just needed to change

```
getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

to

```
getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

I'm new to Fragments, so I guess this is a common error.  Thanks.